# Encrypt a chef databag LOCALLY

Tags: encryption, chef-infra, knife

Im trying to encrypt a file using knife LOCALLY. I dont want that my results are saved on my chef server. I simply want to decrypt the file locally, make a few changes and then encrypt it again and save the output to some file.

I am able to decrypt and modify the file just fine. But when I try to encrypt it back I get the below error.

```
knife file encrypt './my_unencrypted.json' --secret-file './my_secret' -Fj > myoutput

FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: 'file encrypt ./my_unencrypted.json --secret-file ./my_secret -Fj'
Available subcommands: (for details, knife SUB-COMMAND --help)
```

Can someone help me? 
BTW, my Chef version is 11.6. For other people this is working ifne and we all share the same version.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

We don't really support this. Databag encryption is not designed for storing the encrypted contents into source control so we don't make this particularly easy. In general is not expected that encrypted bags will exist locally as anything other than ephemeral files.